# wordpress - date_query to get posts only from certain date

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am trying to pull the posts whose `post_date` is equal to certain date (`$date` in my case), usually wordpress `post_date` is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format but since my input will not have `hh:mm:ss` value I have written the code as below but seems to be not working, can anyone suggest me if I am following the right pattern for `date_query`. Below is my code.

```
    // setup query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
    'date_query' => array(
        'column'  => 'post_date',
        'after' =>  $date.' 00:00:00',
        'before' =>  $date.' 23:59:59',
//            'compare' => '=',
  ),
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
// query database
$order_list = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split your date up into the year, month and day you can format your date query like the following:

```
<?php
// setup query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => $year,
            'month' => $month,
            'day' => $day,
        )        
    ),
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id(),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
// query database
$order_list = new WP_Query($args);
```

For more info on the [Date Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)